# Nock throws a no match for request when using Promise.race

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, nock

I'm writing a test for some code that will use `Promise.race` to bring back a result from a graphql service that is on (could be on) multiple servers.  I've used [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) to mock the request, which works fine when I'm hitting a single service.  When I mock up multiple services, Nock throws an error saying

> AssertionError: expected [Function] to not throw an error but 'Error: Error: Nock: No match for request {\n  "method": "POST",\n  "url": "http://94.82.155.133:35204",\n  "headers": {\n    "content-type": "application/json",\n    "accept": "application/json"\n  },\n  "body": "{...}"\n}' was thrown

my test looks like this:

```
it('should make two POST requests to the service for data from graphQL', async () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(releases, '_queryGraphQL');
  const releaseID = 403615894;
  nock.cleanAll();
  const services = serviceDetails(NUMBER_OF_SERVICES); // NUMBER_OF_SERVICES = 3
  nock(serviceDiscoveryHost)
    .get('/v1/catalog/service/state51')
    .reply(HTTP_CODES.OK, services);

  for (const service of services) {
    const currentNodeHealth = nodeHealth(service.Node);
    nock(serviceDiscoveryHost)
      .get('/v1/health/node/'+service.Node)
      .reply(HTTP_CODES.OK, currentNodeHealth);

    const delayTime = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    nock('http://'+service.Address+':'+service.ServicePort, serviceHeaders)
      .post('/')
      .delay(delayTime)
      .replyWithError({code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: false})
      .post('/')
      .delay(delayTime)
      .reply(HTTP_CODES.OK, getReply(releaseID))
  }

  const actual = await releases.getRelease(releaseID)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(releases._retries);
      (() => { throw err; }).should.not.throw();
    });
  expect(releases._retries[releaseID]).to.be.equal(1);
  expect(spy.callCount).to.be.equal(2);
  expect(actual).to.be.an('object')
  expect(actual.data.ReleaseFormatById.id).to.be.equal(releaseID);
});
```

and the offending bit of code looks like

```
async _queryGraphQL(releaseID, services) {
    if (! this._retries[releaseID]) {
      this._retries[releaseID] = 0;
    }

    const postData = this._getReleaseQuery(releaseID);

    return Promise.race(services.map( (service) => {
      const options = this._getHTTPRequestOptions(service);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let post = this.http.request(options, (res) => {
          let data = '';
          if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
            const msg = this.SERVICE_NAME + ' returned a status code outside of acceptable range: ' + res.statusCode;
            reject(new QueryError(msg, postData));
          } else {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
              data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('error', (err) => {
              reject(new QueryError(err.message, postData, err));
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
              resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            });
          }
        });
        post.on('error', async (err) => {
          if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
            if (this._retries[releaseID] &&
                this._retries[releaseID] === 3) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              this._retries[releaseID] += 1;
              resolve(this._queryGraphQL(releaseID, services));
            }
          } else {
            reject(new QueryError(err.message, postData, err));
          }
        });

        post.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
        post.end();
      });
    }));
  }
```

`this.http` is just `require('http');`. and the options will be `{hostname: service.hostname} \\ example.com` etc.

What I'm expecting, is that if the first service to respond, responds with an error relating to: 'ETIMEDOUT', it'll recall the function (upto 2 more times) and try all the services again until the first service to respond is something that isn't a 'ETIMEDOUT'.

Comment: I don't see anything that stands out as being wrong. Why do you think the Promise.race is the culprit? Have you verified that the headers and origin for that error match what you expect?